# Difference between maven project and other projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Currently I am using eclipse and ant build for my application. Right now I am migrating the building phase from ant to maven.There I got confused which to use.

Whether to use **mvn eclipse:eclipse** which actually creates .project and  .classpath then import it from eclipse as java project

or

to use **m2e plugin** and import my project as maven project

Comment: There's no much difference. Do you have a POM already, and did you configure your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

`mvn eclipse:eclipse` only creates an Eclipse Java project configuration files (so you lately can import that project into Eclipse workspace using original eclipse import action) rather than `m2e plugin` imports a Maven project to the Eclipse and makes it a Java project too.

Comment: can u share the pros and cons of both.I felt m2e plugin gives me burden since some of the plugins are not supported and I need to exclude that via m2e plugin and certain feature of maven such -f are not support in m2e yet

Comment: it's not the same, if you want to work with maven project in eclipse even without m2e plugin you use first option, but if you want to use m2e plugin then second.